# MagicaVoxel export world in 1 model

Tags: obj, export, magicavoxel

So I'm currently working in MagicaVoxel and I have 2 objects in my world. When I export it as .obj it exports as seperate 2 obj models with 2 seperate textures and materials. Is there any way that I can export whole MagicaVoxel world to single object. If there is a way this would really made my work easier because I will add more objects to world.

Thank you for answers.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using some intermediate app to combine them? For instance, export from MagicaVoxel, combine the objects in Blender (or something else) and then use the file as needed.

Comment: No, not really but thank you for mentioning that.

Comment: Just what I already gave as an example - open the .obj file in something else (such as Blender or any other 3D editing app that supports .obj), combine the object in that app & then save the file. This doesn't address your question of how to do it directly in MagicaVoxel (which would be easier assuming it's possible), but it might be good enough in the absence of better options.

Comment: Thank you it worked perfect. I just imported obj models into Blender and set their position to (0,0,0) and everything aligned perfect.

Comment: In that case I'll write it up as an actual answer rather than a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of a way to do this directly within the current version of MagicaVoxel (0.99.4 [5/29/2019]).

It's not uncommon for special purpose apps to lack the full functionality of more general purpose main stream software. To get around these limitations, you may need to chain together more than one piece of software to accomplish your goal.

In this case, I recommend opening the `.obj` file exported from MagicaVoxel in a general 3d modelling app such as Blender, Maya, 3ds Max, etc. I know that Blender in particular has support for taking multiple objects/meshes and combining such that they are represented as one object.

After combining the objects, simply save the file and use it as desired.

As a final note, if you have a significant number of files to process, you should consider automating the task if possible. Most modeling software that I'm familiar with has a scripting language for automating repetitive tasks.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I do it:

1. Switch to a Objects View [Tab]
2. Select all objects [Ctrl+a] and Press "Union"
3. Export .obj (which now should export the project as a single object)
4. Undo the Union operation [Ctrl-z]

[image: Union all objects]